# jquery strange behavior when setting the value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am a little baffled by this issue I encountered.

I have an `<input type="text" />` element in a template that I am cloning when creating object items.

```
function buildSectionTest(item) {
if (item == null)
    return;
var sectionItem = $('.templates-mc .templates-mc-section-item').clone();

$('.mc-label', sectionItem).text(item.TestDescription);
$('.mc-input', sectionItem).attr({ 'testid': item.ID, 'syntax': item.TestSyntax, 'value': item.Value });
//$('.mc-input', sectionItem).val("TEST");
//alert($('.mc-input').attr('value');
//alert($('.mc-input').val());

return sectionItem.html(); 
}
```

However, the value property is not being set. Looking at the rendered html reveals:

```
<input class="mc-input rounded-corners" type="text" testid="6446" syntax="[input]">
```

I have tried a few things (commented out in the above code) but all return empty string, or no value.

Initially I thought that I may be clearing all input fields (for what ever strange reason), but this is not the case.

my item.Value is not null or undefined.

Has anybody else encountered this issue?

Appreciate all input!

Comment: Try logging the contents of item.Value are you sure it's not [input]

Comment: Also share how `buildSectionTest` is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the value use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$('.mc-input', sectionItem).attr({ 'testid': item.ID, 'syntax': item.TestSyntax}).val(item.Value);
```

Ex:

```
function buildSectionTest(item) {
    if (item == null)
        return;

    var sectionItem = $('.templates-mc .templates-mc-section-item').clone();

    $('.mc-label', sectionItem).text(item.TestDescription);
    $('.mc-input', sectionItem).attr({ 'testid': item.ID, 'syntax': item.TestSyntax}).val(item.Value);
    //$('.mc-input', sectionItem).val("TEST");
    //alert($('.mc-input').attr('value');
    //alert($('.mc-input').val());

    return sectionItem; //do not return the html
}
```

Comment: I have used .val as well, this is why I find it strange that it isn't working. If you see I have commented out a couple things in my code where I directly tested .val("test"); but it's not setting it at all.

Comment: Also do not return `sectionItem.html();` you need to return `sectionItem;`

Comment: Thank you Arun - removing the .html() seems to have worked. I assume that sectionItem preserves the jquery object.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$('.mc-input', sectionItem).attr({ 'testid': item.ID, 'syntax': item.TestSyntax, this.val(item.Value) });
```

Comment: It's not even valid Javascript syntax. Everything inside an object literal has to be in the form `property: value`.

Comment: And you're not using `this` properly at all.